# Replace all the substrings within a couple of delimiters in Java

Tags: java, string

Maybe the question seems to be stupid, but I have to handle with several Gbs of text files to be preprocessed.

Is there any efficient and possibly elegant way in Java to remove from a `String` all the substrings that are between two `String`s used as delimiter? E.g. when you define two delimiters, say `([` and `])`, then from the `String` *"Hi ([bla bla]) how are ([test]) you?"* a new String *"Hi how are you?"* must be returned.

The simplest way that I found is the following:

```
String text = "Hi ([bla bla]) how are ([test]) you?";
while(text.contains("([") && text.contains("])")){
  text = text.substring(0, text.indexOf("(["))+
        text.substring(text.indexOf("])")+"]))".length());
}
System.out.println(text);  //Prints "Hi how are you?"
```

where `([` and `])` are the delimiters.

External library globally used (e.g. Apache libraries) are also welcome, but the standard Java API is preferred.

Comment: Take a look at the java.util.Scanner class, or else look at java.util.regex.*, e.g.: Pattern.compile("\\[[^]]+\\]") and iterate through the matches with .appendReplacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there is no nesting involved, you can use regular expressions:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\(\\[.*?\\]\\)", "");
```

If you want to deal with spaces:

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\s*\\(\\[.*?\\]\\)\\s*", " ");
```

Comment: Yes, I think that no nesting will be given.

Comment: I have to report that I gest extra spaces, i.e. `Hi  how are  you?`

Comment: Yeah! Perfect! Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace all

```
input.replaceAll("\[[^\]]*\]", "");
```

Comment: I get the following message from the Netbeans IDE: "Illegal escape character"

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is the easier way, but probably on big files, the more efficient way in Java is going with a binary search, that is reading byte-per-byte with a RandomAccessFile - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html.